# is it possible to TAG emails in lotus notes 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes

I am newbie to Lotus Notes and I am finding it difficult to categorize my mails using it.

Is it possible to tag emails in version 8.5?

Comment: You are aware that you can use folders to sort email though right?

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can tag emails in Lotus Notes. It is just not called "tagging" because the functionality predates the concept of tagging. It is called "Categorize" - In single user mode (as your mail file) there is no difference between tagging and categorizing (in multi-user mode categorizing misses the "who-did-that").

So you can go to you Actions menu and categorize any mail/task/calendar entry even if the field is not visual. You also can add a smart icon in your toolbar (File - Preferences - Toolbar - Customize - New(Button) - Formula: @Command([ToolsCategorize])

What you then need (final step) is either to create or edit a view to show the "categories" field categorized. I would use a new view since it will survive a template upgrade

Comment: Sounds great but I don't have "Categorize" in my Actions menu. Could it have been disabled by my company?

Comment: Use a smart icon then

Comment: Okay that works, but often when I click the new "categorize" button, I get an error: _The first categorized column in this view does not sort on the CATEGORIES field. Choose another categorized view using the View menu._ -- this implies I can only categorize an email if it's already displayed in a categorized view, although it does also work in the 'Mail Threads' view. **How do I categorize emails from the Inbox?**

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately tagging is not supported in the IBM-supported mail template.

Comment: "category" is similar to tagging - see @stwissel's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but there is no categorize option for email itmes in the lots notes 8.5 that I run.  Perhaps each corporation that uses it can make a custom UI template but it certainly isn't default or out of the box behavior as stwissel indicates.

Answer (score 1):

One of the great things about Notes Mail is that the source code is open.  So a notes developer could add some kind of tagging functionality if you need it.

But out of the box it's not there.  You can add the same email to MULTIPLE folders.  So you could create folder for common tags or "categories".  You can also add a "Flag" to an email with a followup action note and date.